# How to restart Perl script running under mod_fcgid when changed?

Tags: perl, mod-fcgid

I'm running some FastCGI scripts under `mod_fcgid`, and I'd like those to reload automatically whenever I make any changes to the script.

Under `mod_fastcgi`, you can configure

```
FastCgiConfig -autoUpdate
```

to do exactly that, but `mod_fcgid` doesn't have such an option.
Anyone have a good workaround for this?

The best thing I came up with, is:

```
while (my $cgi = CGI::Fast->new()) {
    processRequest($cgi);
    exit if -M $0 < 0;  # restart if script changed
}
```

which exits after handling one more request.  But this is not ideal, especially when there are multiple instances of the script running, it might take quite a while before all old instances had an opportunity to run once more and exit.

If I do the `exit` before `processRequest`, the user gets an error, so that won't do either.

Thanks in advance,

– Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do it is a little bit subtle. I would recommend looking at [Plack::Loader::Restarter](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aLoader%3a%3aRestarter) for how to do it, or better yet adapting you app to run on Plack and then just launching it with plackup's `-r` option to load the restarter automatically. Adapting your app might be easier than you expect, possibly as easy as changing

```
use CGI::Fast;
while (my $cgi = CGI::Fast->new) {
    processRequest($cgi);
}
```

to

```
use CGI::Emulate::PSGI;
use CGI;

my $app = CGI::Emulate::PSGI->handler(sub {
    my $cgi = CGI->new;
    processRequest($cgi);
});
```

(writing a proper native PSGI app is even nicer, but this version saves you from rewriting most of your app).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this at all, but would [`Module::Refresh`](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3A%3ARefresh) work for your `mod_fcgid` purposes?

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and I suppose it would work.  However, it is a bit of overkill for a few simple CGI scripts to have to put the actual code in a separate module.  But thanks anyway.